# PHP form submission opens empty page

Tags: php, html, forms

I copied the code for a form to my website. It doesn't submit... Can someone see the problem?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
$email_to = "danielko@intrahouse.co.il";
$email_subject = "פנייה מהאתר";


function died($error) {
    // your error code can go here
    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo " מלא את כל הפרטים בבקשה.<br /><br />";
    die();
}

  // validation expected data exists
  if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email']) ||
    !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
    !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
    died(' אחד הפרטים חסר. מלא את כל הפרטים בבקשה');       
}

$first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
$telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
$comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

$error_message = "נא מלא פרטים נכונים";
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
$error_message .= 'נא מלא פרטים נכונים.<br />';
}
if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
$error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
died($error_message);
}
 $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
$email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
$email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>





<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" dir"=rtl">
<meta name="keywords" content="פורום בית חכם,בית חכם, חשמל חכם, בקרת חשמל, ניהול חשמל,     חסכון בחשמל, אמצעי בקרת חשמל, כמה עולה בית חכם, מחירי חשמל חכם, מערכות בית חכם, תכנון בית חכם">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="contact_style.css" type="text/css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"    type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.uniform.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function(e){
$("input:checkbox, input:radio").uniform();
$('#top').css('float','none');
$('.content_window').css('height','auto');
});
</script>
<title>IntraHouse - צור קשר</title>

</head>

<body>
<div class="background">
<div class="content_window">
<header>
<div class="languages">
        <a href="indexEnglish.html">English</a>
        <a href="index.html">עברית</a>
    </div>
<div id="app_theme" style="margin-top:3px" ></div>
    <div id="top" style="margin-top:2px" style="float:none" >
        <nav id="topmenu">
            <ul>
                <li id="home"><a href="index.html">דף הבית </a></li>
                <li id="about"><a href="#">אודות </a></li>
                <li id="prices"><a href="prices.html">מחירים</a></li>
                <li id="projects"><a href="projects.html">פרוייקטים</a></li>
                <li id="store"><a href="store.html">חנות</a></li>
                <li id="contact_us"><a href="contact_us.html">צור קשר</a></li>            
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
<div class="contact" style="margin-top:10px">
<article dir="rtl">
<h1 style="margin-top:10px"> נשמע מעניין? השאירו פרטים ונחזור אליכם</h1>
<form>
<ul>
    <li>
        <label for="name"> שם: </label>
        <input type="text" size="40" id="name" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="telephone"> טלפון: </label>
        <input type="text" size="40" id="name" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="email"> כתובת אימייל: </label>
        <input type="email" size="40" id="email" />
    </li>  

    </li>     
        <li>
        <label for="message">תוכן ההודעה:</label>
        <textarea cols="50" rows="5" id="message"></textarea>
    </li>
</ul>
<p>
    <button type="reset" class="right"> אפס </button>
    <button type="submit" class="action"> שלח </button>

</p>
</form>
</article>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<?php
}
?>
```

HTML appears at the end, as you can see. All buttons work and email @ check work, but the form submmision just opens an empty page.

Comment: died is not a function die is a function

Comment: It is, it's defined at the top.

Comment: What do you mean by "empty" - a blank white page? The form with no values? Does the email get sent?

Comment: You should try to acquire some basic knowledge about PHP if you're going to be using it for your website's contact form. SO is not really meant to be a place where people can correct code you've copied from elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your `form` has no `method` or `action` I believe this doesn't work in some browsers.

Change

```
<form>
```

To:

```
<form method="post" action="[the url of the page]">
```

Answer (score 0):

The default method for a form is `GET` so if you don't specify it in the form tag, you would need `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`.

You also need an action attibute, so your tag should look like:

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

Then you would also need to add `name` attributes to all your form fields as that is what gets sent to the server, not the `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two crucial problems. The id of an HTML element needs to be unique, so here you have two elements with the same id:

```
<li>
    <label for="name"> שם: </label>
    <input type="text" size="40" id="name" />
</li>
<li>
    <label for="telephone"> טלפון: </label>
    <input type="text" size="40" id="name" />
</li>
```

This needs to change, and also each element needs a `name` attribute, or it will not appear in the POST array properly:

```
<li>
    <label for="name"> שם: </label>
    <input type="text" size="40" id="name" name="name" />
</li>
<li>
    <label for="telephone"> טלפון: </label>
    <input type="text" size="40" id="telephone" name="telephone" />
</li>
```

Etc. - all element must have a name and a unique id. In particular, your email field needs `name="email"` so that your `if(isset($_POST['email']))` check at the beginning of the script will work. Also, the form needs the method POST in order for those elements to pass into the POST array. If you simply omit the action, the form will submit to the same page:

```
<form method="POST">
```

Answer (score 0):

your `<form>` should have `method="POST"` attribute
like this :

```
<form method="POST">
```

You have errors :

```
<input type="email" size="40" id="email" />
```

it should be

```
<input type="text" size="40" id="email" name="email" />
```

See, you have `$_POST['first_name']` in your code, so you must have `<input type="text" name="first_name" />` , a `name` attribute is a must.

in order to  get the value of an input field in php you have to use `name` attribute